# iOS: How to clean data before app crash

Tags: ios

I am downloading data in background.
So if user press home button and force quit app by double click on the app icon, then I need some data cleaning.
I try to do data cleaning in the delegate method `applicationWillTerminate` but app did not call this method while crashes. 
I can not do data cleaning in `applicationDidEnterBackground` as my app keeps data downloading in background. I search many hours.. but I am clueless about this.

Can anyone tell me, Is there any way to call method(to clean data) before app  crashes.

Thanks!

Comment: If the user quits the app manually, it doesn't "crash". It just force quits then.

Comment: crash? i didnt see any crash on user quits the app.If you are refering to the xcode screen debugging .It is not a crash

Answer (score 0):

You can't clean up data if your app crashes or is forcefully quit.
You can instead clean the data the next time it's being opened. Depending on what you're doing, you could use a flag inside `NSUserDefaults` that will let you know if data needs to be cleaned or not.

For instance, when the download starts, you can set:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"pendingDownload"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

When download finishes:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"pendingDownload"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"pendingDownload"] boolValue]){
    // clean data
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"pendingDownload"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Yes we can do this way..but in my case I can't clean code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ..